# How to display all values stored in an array and how to pass those values to a second function {C}

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

The main object of the  program is to display all the values within the array called "channels" so that the user can see all the possible choices. After I prompt the user to choose one of the four channels I need to pass those values on to second function in order to calculate something. This is what i have so far.

I also cannot use any loops.

Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

// I'm using a structure to store all the values within the array

```
typedef struct

{
   char* name;
   double n; //roughness
   double slope;
   double width;
   double depth;

} CHANNEL;


main ()
{

    CHANNEL channels [4] = {
    {"Channel1", 0.035, 0.0001, 10.0, 2.0},
    {"Channel2", 0.020, 0.0002, 8.0, 1.0},
    {"Channel3", 0.015, 0.0010, 20.0, 1.5},
    {"Channel4", 0.030, 0.0007, 24.0, 3.0}
    };
```

//I want to display all the channels and their values right here... i know i have to use printf but would i need to use a pointer?

```
    printf("Please note:\n 0 = Channel 1 \n 1 = Channel 2 \n 2 = Channel 3 \n 3 = Channel 4);


    printf("Pick a channel from 0-3\n");
    int c = 0;
    scanf("%i", &c);
    CHANNEL chosen = channels [c];

}
```

//Here is what i have for the second function so far, I have the formula on how to calculate velocity but i don't know how to pass the chosen values and also would i still need to put a function prototype at the top?

```
    CHANNEL calculateVelocity(CHANNEL channels[])
    {
         double velocity;

         //THIS IS THE EQUATION I NEED TO USE 
         //velocity = (slope/n)*(pow((width/depth)/width +2 * depth),(2/3)); 


    }
```

Comment: So basically you want to pass the selected `CHANNEL` to the function, and use its member variables?

Comment: @BenceKaulics yes thats exactly what i want to do

Comment: Side note. You are missing `"` from your `printf` calls.

Comment: oh thanks didn't see that

Comment: Why can't you use any loops?

Comment: @JohnBode we haven't learned them in class yet

Comment: @AjAlmero: That's unfortunate; displaying items in an array is the perfect use case for a loop.  I find it interesting that your instructor chose to teach arrays and function definitions before basic control structures.

Comment: @johnbode if it actually works better with loops could you show mw how to do it?

Comment: "*yes thats exactly what i want to do*" then do not pass `CHANNEL channels[]`  but just pass `CHANNEL channel` to `calculateVelocity()`. And access `channel`s members like `channel.slope`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the missing `"` from the `printf` calls (from both of them) and that you forgot the return value of the `main` which is this way is default `int` you have started pretty well.

`CHANNEL chosen` is now the selected channel, to use its data you have to pass it to your function. As you are going to use its values and you do not want to change them, you can pass it by value to your function.

You function should return `double` as velocity is `double`. To access the member variables the following sytnax have to be used:

```
double calculateVelocity(const CHANNEL selected)
{
     double velocity;
     double n = selected.n;
     double slope = selected.slope;
     double width = selected.width;
     double depth = selected.depth;

     //THIS IS THE EQUATION I NEED TO USE
     velocity = (slope/n)*pow(((width/depth)/width +2 * depth),(2.0/3.0));

     return velocity;
}
```

If I were you I would also check the input from the console, so you won't pass a wrong index to your `channels` array.

```
int main ()
{
    CHANNEL channels [4] = {
    {"Channel1", 2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0},
    {"Channel2", 0.020, 0.0002, 8.0, 1.0},
    {"Channel3", 0.015, 0.0010, 20.0, 1.5},
    {"Channel4", 0.030, 0.0007, 24.0, 3.0}
    };

    printf("Please note:\n 0 = Channel 1 \n 1 = Channel 2 \n 2 = Channel 3 \n 3 = Channel 4\n");

    printf("Pick a channel from 0-3\n");
    int c = 0;
    scanf("%i", &c);

    if(c < 0 || c > 3)
    {
        printf("Input is invalid: %d\n", c);
        return 1;
    }

    CHANNEL chosen = channels [c];

    printf("Calculated velocity: %f\n" ,calculateVelocity(chosen));

    return 0;
}
```

and include `math.h` for `pow`.

Comment: You might like to explain why to use intermediate variables inside `calculateVelocity()` and not just use the members of the struct passed to the function.

Comment: @alk I did not want to mess up the readability of the code nor the original equation. And also I find it more clear to see the syntax.

Comment: Nitpick: The conversion specifier `f` expects a `double`, no need to prefix the length modifier `l` (ell).

Answer (score 0):

Lets go through each of your questions one at a time. Right now, I doubt your `printf` statement is doing what you intend it to. To print each channel and the elements it contains, I would suggest creating a helper function, perhaps looking something like:

```
void CHANNEL_print(CHANNEL* channel) {

    printf("%s\n", channel->name);
    printf("%lf\n", n); // Note that %lf is for doubles
    // print the rest of the values just like this...
}
```

I'm not going tho complete the function in it's entirety because it appears that this question is a homework problem of some sort (why else would you not use a loop??) and I don't want to give away the answer completely. You should be able to figure the rest out quite easily though.

As for the second function, you are correct in that a function prototype or the definition itself would be required before calling it. It appears that you only want to use one `CHANNEL` in the function, so your prototype should look something like

`double calculateVelocity(CHANNEL* channel)`

since (I assume) you want to return the velocity you calculate. The pointer should be a pointer to the channel that you want to pass to the function (i.e. `&channel[c]`) Then, the calculation itself inside the function would look like:

`velocity = (channel->slope / channel->n) * pow((channel->width / channel->depth) / channel->width + 2 * channel->depth, 2.0/3.0)`

Note that `2/3 = 0` since it's integer division, and there was an extra `)` in your equation.

Comment: would i have to state that helper function before main or after

Comment: You can either declare a function prototype before `main` and define the function after, or both declare and define the function before main. Whichever you choose is up to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

just a side note, you need function prototype if the definition of the function is in an external module or the definition of the function comes after a call to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you're not allowed to use loops, but iterating through an array is pretty much the ideal use case for using a loop.  Here's how I would use a loop to display the contents of your array:

```
printf( "%20s%8s%8s%8s%8s\n", "Name", "N", "Slope", "Width", "Depth" );
printf( "%20s%8s%8s%8s%8s\n", "----", "-", "-----", "-----", "-----" );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) // where N is the number of rows in the array
{
  printf( %20s%8.3f%8.4f%8.1f%8.1f\n",
    channels[i].name,
    channels[i].n,
    channels[i].slope,
    channels[i].width,
    channels[i].depth
  );
```

This prints out a 2-line header followed by the array contents that will look something like this (I don't have a compiler handy, so I can't code it up and post output):

```
                Name        N   Slope   Width   Depth
                ----        -   -----   -----   -----
            Channel1    0.035  0.0001    10.0     2.0
            Channel2    0.020  0.0002     8.0     1.0
            Channel3    0.015  0.0010    20.0     1.5
            ...
```

In your case, N would be 4.

The structure of a `for` loop is

```
 for (  expr1opt ; expr2opt ; expr3opt ) statement
```

In a `for` loop, `expr1` is evaluated first; this expression usually initializes a loop counter or some other condition.  Then `expr2` is evaluated; if it evaluates to a non-zero value (`true`) then the body of the loop is executed.  After the loop body executes, `expr3` is evaluated; this usually updates the loop counter or updates some other condition.  Then `expr2` is evaluated again.  The loop body is executed as long as `expr2` evaluates to non-zero.

Any or all of `expr1`, `expr2`, and `expr3` may be omitted.

A few words on the `printf` format strings...

A format specifier takes the form

```
% [flags] [field-width] [. precision] [length-modifier] conversion-specifier
```

So, `%20s` means "print a string in a field that's at least 20 characters wide, padded with blanks to the left." `%8.3f` means print a floating point value in a field that's at least 8 characters wide including the decimal point, with no more than 3 digits after the decimal point."